# Interest On Balance Calculation Repayments

Tags: c#, math, finance

I am trying to design some code that will calculate a repayment plan for a loan, given a principle amount, term period (12 months) and and interest rate. I want the payments each month to be the same value (the last can differ slightly to account for remainders), and the interest is calculated from the remaining loan balance.

The basic rules are

- Interest is dependant on the loan balance.
- Loan balance is dependant on the total monthly repayment value.
- Capital repayment is dependant on total monthly repayment value and interest.
- The total monthly repayment amount can vary but must be the same each month (except the last one which can be different).

Here is the code I currently have, it does continous iterations until it finds the correct total monthly repayment value. This does work sort of but seems very inefficient and it takes the balance horribly into negative when it shouldnt . I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better way of doing this?

```
 static void calcRepaymentPlan()
    {
        decimal loanAmount = 100000; //100,000
        decimal ir = 0.10m;

        //day counts
        int[] days = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        //get month/days
        int dayCount = days.Sum();
        int months = days.Length;

        //get interest values
        decimal interestdaily = ir / dayCount;

        //total each month
        decimal ideal_total_repayment = (loanAmount / months); //random number but seems like the best place to start

        //some arrays to store balances
        decimal[] balances = null;
        decimal[] interest = null;
        decimal[] capitalrepayment = null;

        decimal totalRepaymentsValue = 0;
        while (totalRepaymentsValue != loanAmount)
        {
            //array for balance each month
            balances = new decimal[months];
            for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
            {
                balances[i] = loanAmount - ((i+1) * ideal_total_repayment);
            }

            //array for interest each month
            interest = new decimal[months];
            for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
            {
                interest[i] = (interestdaily * balances[i]) * days[i];
            }

            //array for capital each month
            capitalrepayment = new decimal[months];
            for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
            {
                capitalrepayment[i] = ideal_total_repayment - interest[i];
            }

            //how much of the loan are we paying back?
            totalRepaymentsValue = capitalrepayment.Sum();

            //how much difference between the loan amount and the total we have got now?
            decimal difference = loanAmount - totalRepaymentsValue;

            //how much to increment 
            decimal incr = 1;

            //are we within 100? if so make the increment finer
            if (difference < 100)
                incr = 0.1m;

            //if the difference is less than 1, then just add/subtract it from the last repayment
            if (difference < 1)
            {
                capitalrepayment[months - 1] += difference;
                balances[months - 1] += difference;

                //this should now be the 
                totalRepaymentsValue = capitalrepayment.Sum();

                continue;
            }

            //change the ideal total repayment
            ideal_total_repayment += totalRepaymentsValue < loanAmount ? incr : -incr;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("   Balance              Capital         Interest           Total Repayment");

        for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
        {
            string balanceStr = balances[i].ToString("#,##0.00");
            string capitalStr = capitalrepayment[i].ToString("#,##0.00");
            string interestStr = interest[i].ToString("#,##0.00");
            string totalStr = (capitalrepayment[i] + interest[i]).ToString("#,##0.00");

            Console.WriteLine("{0}). {1}         {2}        {3}          {4}", (i + 1),
                balanceStr, capitalStr, interestStr, totalStr);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ideal Total Repayment Value : {0}", ideal_total_repayment);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Repaying : {0}", totalRepaymentsValue);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


    }
```

Comment: You are trying to calculate annuity payments, google it.

Comment: Or Google "loan amortization". There are standard formulas for the monthly payment, although the very last payment needs to be determined separately due to accumulated round-off error.